# How to create a simple world file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello eveyone!!

How to create a simple world file?

a lot of thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4401/how-to-create-a-simple-world-file?/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Open gazebo place all your objects  go to SaveAs and save it, then change your launch file to reference you saved file. After that if you want to replace it, just repeat the process using the SaveAs to replace your launch file.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) with karma: 107 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack37](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5644/jack37/) on 2018-06-18**:
what about if the terminal show some errors like " Error [Param.cc:363]  Unable to set value [-nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan] for key acceleration"?  and when i reopen the world file after i saved it ,the world has not changed?